# Pivot and rename Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a dataframe in the format

```
      Date         Datediff         Cumulative_sum
01 January 2019       1                   5
02 January 2019       1                   7
02 January 2019       2                   15
01 January 2019       2                   8
01 January 2019       3                   13
```

and I want to pivot the column  Datediff from the dataframe such that the end result looks like

```
Index            Day-1    Day-2    Day-3
01 January 2019    5        8        13
02 January 2019    7        15
```

I have used the pivot command shuch that

```
pt = pd.pivot_table(df, index = "Date",
                   columns = "Datediff",
                   values = "Cumulative_sum") \
               .reset_index() \
               .set_index("Date"))
```

which returns the pivoted table

```
                   1        2         3
01 January 2019    5        8        13
02 January 2019    7        15
```

And I can then rename rename the columns using the loop

```
for column in pt:
    pt.rename(columns = {column : "Day-" + str(column)}, inplace = True)
```

which returns exactly what I want. However, I was wondering if there is a faster way to rename the columns when pivoting and get rid of the loop altogether.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df.add_prefix('Day-')
```

In your solution:

```
pt = (pd.pivot_table(df, index = "Date",
                   columns = "Datediff",
                   values = "Cumulative_sum")
        .add_prefix('Day-'))
```