# Pandas - Group by column and then create new columns from result

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame containing 'test results' for different people over multiple tests per person.
It has the columns `name`, `age`, `score`

`scores = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Alex', 'Alex', 'Alex', 'Alex', 'Alex', 'James', 'James', 'James', 'James', 'James', 'James', 'Emily', 'Emily', 'Emily', 'Emily', 'Emily', 'Emily', 'Emily'], 'age': [25, 26, 26, 27, 27, 25, 26, 26, 26, 27, 27, 25, 25, 26, 26, 26, 27, 27], 'score': [10, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 4, 6, 6, 10, 8, 4, 7, 6, 10, 9, 7, 10]})`

```
     name  age  score
0    Alex   25     10
1    Alex   26      0
2    Alex   26      2
3    Alex   27      1
4    Alex   27      2
5   James   25      2
6   James   26      4
7   James   26      6
8   James   26      6
9   James   27     10
10  James   27      8
11  Emily   25      4
12  Emily   25      7
13  Emily   26      6
14  Emily   26     10
15  Emily   26      9
16  Emily   27      7
17  Emily   27     10
```

I have performed a group by on `name` and `age` and aggregating to give the `max_score` for each group (which is the `max` value of the `score` column for an individual in each year)

`age_scores = scores.groupby(['name','age']).agg({"score":'max'})`

The result looks like

```
           score
name  age       
Alex  25      10
      26       2
      27       2
Emily 25       7
      26      10
      27      10
James 25       2
      26       6
      27      10
```

I would like to have a dataframe with one row per person and then a column for the max score at each age

i.e

```
    name  max_25  max_26  max_27
0   Alex      10       2       2
1  James       7      10      10
2  Emily       2       6      10
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pivot and rename Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54419708/pivot-and-rename-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Use `unstack`: `df.groupby(["name", "age"])["score"].max().unstack()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `pivot`, if you want to transform `age_scores`:

```
(age_scores
     .reset_index()
     .pivot('name', 'age', 'score')
     .add_prefix('max_')
     .reset_index()
     .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
```

Output:

```
    name  max_25  max_26  max_27
0   Alex      10       2       2
1  Emily       7      10      10
2  James       2       6      10
```

---

Otherwise, if you don't need `age_scores` as an intermediate dataframe, solution with `unstack` proposed by Chris in comments is probably an easier one:

```
(scores
 .groupby(['name', 'age'])['score'].max()
 .unstack('age')
 .add_prefix('max_')
 .reset_index())
```

Output:

```
age   name  max_25  max_26  max_27
0     Alex      10       2       2
1    Emily       7      10      10
2    James       2       6      10
```

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful and did exactly what I needed :)

Comment: strangely though the reset_index makes `age` the index and I can't seem to get rid of that

Comment: Yes, so that `age` is the name of columns. You can reset it with `df.columns.name = None`, or with `rename_axis` if you want to chain it. I've updated the solution (the `pivot` part of it) to reset that name to None. And if you want more details, here's this [thread on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022845/pandas-index-column-title-or-name?noredirect=1&lq=1)